# Bizare class instantation in adafruit example

Tags: c++, arduino

I can't figure out the benefit to initializing a class instance with this syntax `Adafruit_8x8matrix matrix = Adafruit_8x8matrix();`, when `Adafruit_8x8matrix matrix;` will do. Is there any kind of benefit to the former syntax vs my simplified syntax? I tested both and it makes no difference to the compiler, and I don't have the module that this library is supposed to work with so I can't really benchmark it. I've never seen this syntax anywhere else, so I would really like to know what is up with this.

[Link to example](https://github.com/HSchmale16/Adafruit-LED-Backpack-Library/blob/master/examples/matrix8x8/matrix8x8.ino) I forked it because I like my deps in the same repo as my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the first syntax creates a temporary object and uses that to copy construct the matrix object. The second syntax avoids the extra copy and constructs matrix directly. So your simplified syntax is better. However, a compiler would likely optimize the difference away, so that the resultant object code would end up being the same.

Comment: Is there any possible reason this syntax would be used in an example?

Comment: The only possible reasons are that it is a style choice by the author, or the author just wrote it that way randomly. Both syntaxes have the exact same effect, with the caveat that the shorter way is theoretically more efficient.